# ContainerUser does not exist when docker build a new asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net, docker

Here's my attempt to build a brand new asp.net webapi project that I generated from command "dotnet new webapi"

Then I'm trying to build a docker image out of it

```
C:\Users\preda\Documents\GitHub\dotnet-webapi>docker image build --pull --file "C:\Users\preda\Documents\GitHub\dotnet-webapi/Dockerfile" --tag "dotnetwebapi:latest" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" --platform "windows/amd64" "C:\Users\preda\Documents\GitHub\dotnet-webapi"
[+] Building 0.3s (12/17)                                                                                docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 706B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 383B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0                                                  0.1s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-nanoserver-1809                               0.1s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0@sha256:4d9f2a7141eadcaf9b096103ad407ce374a9bb06f831fe306e03  0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0@sha256:4d9f2a7141eadcaf9b096103ad407ce374a9bb06f831fe306e03ed6378  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 364B                                                                                  0.0s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-nanoserver-1809@sha256:0a2aecea193504c91a6c572e03c5cdce4a  0.0s
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [dotnet-webapi.csproj, ./]                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "dotnet-webapi.csproj"                                                    0.0s
------
 > [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "dotnet-webapi.csproj":
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |     WORKDIR /src
  10 |     COPY ["dotnet-webapi.csproj", "./"]
  11 | >>> RUN dotnet restore "dotnet-webapi.csproj"
  12 |     COPY . .
  13 |     WORKDIR "/src/."
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "cmd /S /C dotnet restore \"dotnet-webapi.csproj\"" did not complete successfully: unable to find user ContainerUser: invalid argument
```

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG configuration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["dotnet-webapi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "dotnet-webapi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "dotnet-webapi.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "dotnet-webapi.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet-webapi.dll"]
```

I'm on windows 11 and docker for windows and ContainerUser does exist

```
C:\Users\preda\Documents\GitHub\dotnet-webapi>net user

user accounts for \\LEGION

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator           ContainerUser            DefaultAccount
Guest                   preda                    WDAGUtilityAccount
```

and ContainerUser is part of docker user group

```
Local Group Memberships                  *docker-users
```